# Remap a key in Ubuntu 20.04, Wayland

Tags: gnome, keyboard, wayland, xmodmap, xkb

I think I\ve looked all over the whole internet for an answer now, but I can\t find it.

I have a keyboard where the tilde key should be mapped to the bar/pipe key. Before Wayland I used this config

```
➜  ~ xmodmap -e "keycode 49 = less greater bar bar bar"
```

But now this config doesnt work in the terminal window, for some strange reason. As far as I understand it shouldnt work at all in Wayland.

As far as I understand `setxkbmap` is the way to go. Ive tried `setxkbmap -option "tlde:bar"` but it doesnt give any effect at all. How do I get further?

**Update**

```
➜  ~ setxkbmap -query
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us

➜  ~ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources
[('xkb', 'se')]

➜  ~ echo $DESKTOP_SESSION
ubuntu-wayland

➜  ~ echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
ubuntu:GNOME
```

Comment: Do you mean `/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev`? How do I check which keyboard layout I'm using? It's an american keyboard.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated it now. Yes, I've looked at that one but I don't know the name (like TLDE for tilde) is for pipe/bar.

Comment: It's the one left of the 1 number key. Sorry, I'm a newbie into this.

Comment: No, I use the laptop keyboard. Now I've updated the Swedish keyboard config file (as you proposed) and when I run `gkbd-keyboard-display -l se` it looks like the key has been accurate mapped, but it doesn't work. Do I need to do anything particular to reload it?

Comment: Holy yes, it works. I updated line 21 in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/se` and then logged out. Thanks a lot! Do I need to do anything to save it permanently?

Comment: Great! Well, it is saved permanently, but since you edited a package owned file it will be overwritten at the next update of the `xbk-data` package. So you may need to redo it once that happens (not very often).

Comment: Okay, thank your very much! You can write an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Please feel free to write the answer yourself. It's perfectly fine to answer your own question. :) (I deleted my answer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of help from @Gunnar Hjalmarsson I've managed to solve it.

In `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/se` I changed key TLDE to

```
     key <TLDE>  { [   greater,    less,    bar, threequarters]  };
```

And then I relogged in and it works! The change will be overwritten next time `xkb-data` package updates, so I'll save a copy in my home folder.